# Sedna, VP113 and the likelihood of the PX/Tyche/Thelistos hypotheses

Tags: astronomy, planets, solar-system, observational-astronomy

The recent discoveries in exoplanetary science (specially those findings of planets orbiting far far away from its parent star/stars) raise questions about how much we know about the (true, AIU definition) number of planets in our solar system.

Question: does the discovery of VP113 and Sedna increase the odds of some kind of planetary object in the edge of the known solar system (Oort's cloud)? How could we find it if it is very cold and dark? I mean, how many Sedna or VP113 objects we would need in order to guess its position and location?

Reading about this topic, I don't know how to quantify the odds of finding

- PX(Planet X): An Earth sized body perturbing the orbits of Sedna, VP113 and other similar objects.
- Thelistos: A super-Earth (about 5-10 Earth masses times a O(1) factor)
- Tyche: (Now disfavoured by WISE data, I think it can not be excluded if it is extremely cold and "dark") Gas giant (Neptune-like, Saturn-like, etc)
- Nemesis: A "dark star"/brown dwarf object.

Comment: The number of planetary objects in the solar system is a matter of definition, as the case of Pluto proves. Where will the IAU set the limits of what constitutes a planetary object in the future? That requires a crystal ball, not a telescope.  The one thing we do know is, that the number will only increase over the short term, as more sensitive instruments become available, and there is no star close enough to separate the already discovered objects from the system.

Comment: Didn't the WISE data also disfavor the Nemesis hypothesis? And such a star would be hot enough to show up on such a survey, thus rendering your "cold" theory useless for Nemesis.

Comment: HDE WISE disfavor Tyche UNLESS it is a very cold or dark/death star...WISE has a lower bound in the IR energy/temperature it can detect. SO Tyche is disfavored up to some COLD low T. I am not in the WISE team so I am not sure of the limit low T WISE ca find in IR...

Comment: Question cross-posted was cross-posted on Astronomy SE: http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/6316/sedna-vp113-and-the-likelihood-of-the-px-tyche-thelistos-hypotheses